# Ionic-angular ion-textarea's height shrink

Tags: angular, google-chrome, ionic-framework, textarea

I'm coding with ionic-angular framework for some project.
When I use ion-textarea, sometimes the textarea's height is decreased 0px.
If the textarea code like that,

```
<ion-textarea class="translated"
  [value]="text">
</ion-textarea>
```

- nomal state

[image]

- shrink state

[image]

In shrink state case, the height of `ion-textarea` is normal but the `div` and `textarea` in the `ion-textarea` get somemthing wrong.

[image]

I want to know what is the cause of this situation and how to solve!!

please let me know what is the problem
(I tested it in chrome browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bad but works:

```
@ViewChild(IonTextarea, {static: false}) ionTextarea: IonTextarea;

async ngAfterViewInit(): Promise<void> {
  await this.checkTextarea();
}

async checkTextarea() {
 return this.ionTextarea.getInputElement().then((element) => {
  if (element.style.height == '0px') {
    return element.style.height = 'auto';
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => this.checkTextarea(), 100)
  }
  
 })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This method can be used temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-textarea class="translated ion-padding"
rows='3'
</ion-textarea>
```

Comment: It also change the height of `ion-textarea`  and there is no change  in div, textarea